# Как сверстать div и картинку так, что бы их суммарная высота равнялась высоте экрана?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Как сделать так что бы сумма высот дива с фиксированной высотой и картинки равнялась высоте экрана? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно с помощью `display: flex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- единицы измерения `vh` работать в старых браузерах не будут

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.main {
  background: silver;
  height: 100vh;
}
.text {
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  margin-top: -5px;
}
img {  
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img src="http://www.joomlack.fr/images/demos/demo2/on-top-of-earth.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse ullam voluptate a ipsa architecto, dolorem voluptates. Eveniet dicta sed quas quidem cum aliquid facilis soluta, facere veritatis modi dolores, dolorum.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: мне кажется, если нужно чтобы суммарная высота была равна высоте экрана, то скролла быть не должно

Comment: да, недоглядел. исправился

Comment: @ lexxl, крут, волшебное решение. Можете что нибудь подсказать для старых браузеров? Первая мысль - отследить версию браузера как нибудь в Meta, и задать постоянную высоту картинки, что бы она ни куда не уехала.

Comment: можно через jQuery высчитывать высоту:  function setHeight() {
  $('целевой_блок').css({
   height: $(window).height() + 'px'
  });
 } - это будет, по сути, аналогично размеру в 100vh

Comment: Мне нравится вариант с минимумом скриптов, я подумываю над разделением этого участка верстки для старых и современных браузеров. Для старых сделаю что нибудь попроще, без привязке к высоте экрана.

Answer (score 1):

1. Можно через js
2. В css3 появилась ф-ция calc, позволяющая высчитывать высоту. В вашем случае расчет делается, видимо, по формуле 100% - 100px, где 100% - высота картинки, а 100px - высота div'a.

Хотя я бы наоборот делал. Качество картинки на больших дисплеях может отличаться от картинки на маленьком дисплее (маленькое разрешение)